Will methyl group donates its electron density to only carbon atoms and not to other heteroatoms ?? Why this is so?
I initially thought in every possible case methyl group always donates its electron density to the atom to which it is bonded. But today I came across a problem, in which it asks us to point out the strongest -I group from given compounds.
Two of them are 
a)

b)

I felt that positive charge on Nitrogen will be stabilized by Electron donating nature of methyl groups, but this lacks in (b), so (b) will show most -I effect on the attached carbon,
But the solution doesn't concerned about the Electron donating nature of methyl group, it says the methyl group is more electronegative than hydrogen, so methyl group here exhibits Electron withdrawing nature, making the positive charge bearing nitrogen even more positive and making it more unstable.
I hope everyone understood the point which I m trying to ask.
In short, my question is ' Why methyl group doesn't exhibit Electron donating nature everytime?? And in which are all cases methyl group will be Electron donating group??
Or If it does exhibit everytime what will be the correct stand for this solution, what might be the reason for (a) to be more -I group than (b) '

The methyl group can and does donate electrons through hyperconjugation to hetetoatoms. Donation to nitogen is suggested by comparing the $\pu{pK_b}$ of methylamine(4.19) with that of ammonia(4.75). The methylamine forms a more stable conjugate acid through electron donation from the methyl groups.
